# Javascript Dynamic Array Calculator/Generator

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to create a dynamic array of integers on Javascript?

Let me explain a little further. I am designing a number generator that allows the user to input 9-13 numbers, select 3 "places" in that array, and input another number to fill those spots, so that the original number is altered in the output.

Example: The user enters 123-12-1234
The user selects the [0], [1], [2]
The user inputs 5
Result: the output is 555-12-1234

Code is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should get you started

```
var arrayOfInts = [];

var input = ""; // accept user input in some way (text input in page?)

arrayOfInts.push(parseInt(input, 10));

// Now work with arrayOfInts
```

Answer (score 0):

There's functions to the Javascript 'Array' object. On  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp,
you can find all functions and properties. Some examples:

```
var list = new Array(123,475,142,89);
```

Adding/deleting an element to/from the array:

```
list.push(286);
    // Added integer '286'
var num = list.pop();
    // Returns the last element and deletes it from the array
var index = list.indexOf(475);
    // Returns the position of element '475' in the array, if present
```

Go check out the link.